# Hosting Mutiple laravel project in sub-directory in same server

Tags: laravel, apache, server, virtualhost

I am struggling to host the multiple laravel project in same server in sub-directory.

I want to run laravel project in `example.com/CoreApp` and `example.com/DataSync`

### Project Directory:

```
 - Root directory (example.com): React Js Project
 - CoreApp (example.com/CoreApp) : Laravel Project
 - DataSync (example.com/DataSync) : Laravel Project
```

### Here is the current issue I am facing now.

- `example.com/`    => It is working fine.
- `example.com/CoreApp`    => It is working fine.
- `example.com/DataSync`    => It is serving me `404 page` whereas its other routes are working fine. Like `example.com/DataSync/telescope is working` fine.

**Note:** Also, I have added `RewriteBase /DataSync` and `RewriteBase /CoreApp` in respective project in `.htaccess`

### Here's my config:

Server Config:

```
 - Digital Ocean Server
 - Apache web server
 - Ubuntu 16
```

Here is what my virtual host look like.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/html

Alias /CoreApp /var/www/sites/html/CoreApp

Alias /DataSync /var/www/sites/html/DataSync

<Directory /var/www/sites/html/CoreApp>
   AllowOverride All
   DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/sites/html/DataSync>
   AllowOverride All
   DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>


 ServerName www.example.com
 ServerAlias www.example.com
 Redirect permanent / https://example.com/

<Directory "/var/www/sites/html">
    Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/html
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/sites/key/myserver.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/sites/certs/example_com.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/sites/certs/example_com.ca-bundle


<Directory "/var/www/sites/html">
    Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: can you customised your apache server configure file?

Comment: Yes. I want to solve the issue above

Answer (score 1):

Change in you virtual host file for Alias as:

```
Alias /CoreApp /var/www/sites/html/CoreApp/public
Alias /DataSync /var/www/sites/html/DataSync/public
```

you have to provide location of public folder

Comment: I have moved all the necessary files from public folder like .htacess, index.php to root dir of the project and made necessary changes to index.php file as well. So would it be the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should provide URL up to **your-directory/public**. If still issue. then provide URL up to **your-directory/public/index.php**.